# Use two functions for x and y coordinates for a plot

Tags: plotting

I try to make a plot out of two functions. It is a cycloid I want to plot. These are my two functions:

```
posPv[t_] = radius*(1 - Cos[2 π*t])
posPh[t_] = radius*(2 π*t - Sin[2 π*t])
```

Does anybody know how to do this. I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: ?ParametricPlot

Comment: [Cycloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cycloid.html), [cycloid parametric](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65962/cycloid-parametric), [Making mathematical animations with Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/making-mathematical-animations-with-mathematica/8834#8834), [WDP](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=cycloid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ParameticPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParameticPlot.html) is what you are looking for.

```
With[{r = 1}, 
  ParametricPlot[r {2 π t - Sin[2 π t], 1 - Cos[2 π t]}, {t, 0, 2}]]
```

[image: plot]